# Sonarqube 5.2 doesn't like working directory as a sym link. How to specify the working dir?

Tags: java, sonarqube

With sonarqube 5.2, it uses Files.createDirectories which does not like if the last part is a sym link.
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8130464

```
Caused by: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /home/bamboo/.sonar
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:88)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.createDirectory(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:383)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectory(Files.java:630)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createAndCheckIsDirectory(Files.java:734)
    at java.nio.file.Files.createDirectories(Files.java:683)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalTempFolderProvider.createTempFolder(GlobalTempFolderProvider.java:83)
    ... 92 more
```

How are you supposed to specify the working directory? I've tried sonar.properties using the key sonar.working.directory but that did not seem to work.
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/CoreProperties.java#L457

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you referred is used to define the working directory within the project being analysed.

The problem you are having is related to the sonar home directory, which is usually global per user and located in `~/.sonar`.

Try with `sonar.userHome`.

The path is defined here: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-batch/src/main/java/org/sonar/batch/bootstrap/GlobalTempFolderProvider.java#L95

Comment: Thank you very much!

That pointed me in the right direction. I couldn't get the sonar.properties to work, but I used the env var SONAR_USER_HOME for our CI server's user and that worked.